# Plotly: How to set style and color for the arrows using add_annotations?

Tags: r, vector, plotly, arrows

I want to represent 2D vectors rooted at the origin with plotly in R. Moreover, I want to color the vector based on a categorical variable. The problem is that I can either create the lines color-coded but without the arrow head:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

v <- c(1, 1)
b1 <- c(1, 0)
b2 <- c(0, 1)
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(v[1], b1[1], b2[1]),
  y = c(v[2], b1[2], b2[2]),
  is_basis = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)
df %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~is_basis) %>%
  add_segments(xend = ~x, yend = ~y, x = 0, y = 0, colors = c("red","black"))
```

Or with the arrow-head but not color-coded:

```
df %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~is_basis) %>%
  add_annotations(x = ~x, y = ~y, showarrow = TRUE, text = "", ax = 0, ay = 0,
                  axref = "x", ayref = "y", xref = "x", yref = "y")
```

So, my question is: Can I add an arrow head with add_segments? Or, can I style and color the arrows generated with add_annotations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can chose arrowhead and set the color of the arrow through the arguments `arrowhead` and `arrowcolor` in the function `add_annotations()`. If you set `axref = "x"` and `ayref = "y"` you also make sure that the lines start at origo if you set `ax` and `ay` to `0`.
Here's an example using a subset of the built-in dataset mtcars:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

data <- mtcars[which(mtcars$am == 1 & mtcars$gear == 4),]
#data <- data %>% filter(row.names(data) %in% c("Honda Civic", "Fiat X1-9", "Datsun 710"))
#row.names(data) <- c("Honda Civic", "Fiat X1-9", "Datsun 710")

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
        marker = list(size = 2)) #%>%

p <- p %>%
  add_annotations(x = data["Honda Civic","wt"],
                  y = data["Honda Civic","mpg"],
                  text = "",
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  showarrow = TRUE,
                  arrowcolor='blue',
                  arrowhead = 1,
                  arrowsize = 2,
                  ax = 0,
                  ay = 0,
                  axref="x",
                  ayref='y',
                  font = list(color = '#264E86',
                              family = 'sans serif',
                              size = 14))

p <- p %>%
  add_annotations(x = data["Fiat X1-9","wt"],
                  y = data["Fiat X1-9","mpg"],
                  text = "",
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  showarrow = TRUE,
                  arrowcolor='green',
                  arrowhead = 2,
                  arrowsize = 2,
                  ax = 0,
                  ay = 0,
                  axref="x",
                  ayref='y',
                  font = list(color = '#264E86',
                              family = 'sans serif',
                              size = 14))

p <- p %>%
  add_annotations(x = data["Datsun 710","wt"],
                  y = data["Datsun 710","mpg"],
                  text = "",
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  showarrow = TRUE,
                  arrowcolor='red',
                  arrowhead = 3,
                  arrowsize = 2,
                  ax = 0,
                  ay = 0,
                  axref="x",
                  ayref='y',
                  font = list(color = '#264E86',
                              family = 'sans serif',
                              size = 14))

p <- p %>%
  add_annotations(x = data["Fiat 128","wt"],
                  y = data["Fiat 128","mpg"],
                  text = "",
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  showarrow = TRUE,
                  arrowcolor='black',
                  arrowhead = 4,
                  arrowsize = 2,
                  ax = 0,
                  ay = 0,
                  axref="x",
                  ayref='y',
                  font = list(color = '#264E86',
                              family = 'sans serif',
                              size = 14))

p <- p %>%
  add_annotations(x = data["Mazda RX4 Wag","wt"],
                  y = data["Mazda RX4 Wag","mpg"],
                  text = "",
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  showarrow = TRUE,
                  arrowcolor='purple',
                  arrowhead = 5,
                  arrowsize = 2,
                  ax = 0,
                  ay = 0,
                  axref="x",
                  ayref='y',
                  font = list(color = '#264E86',
                              family = 'sans serif',
                              size = 14))


p <- p %>%
  add_annotations(x = data["Volvo 142E","wt"],
                  y = data["Volvo 142E","mpg"],
                  text = "",
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  showarrow = TRUE,
                  arrowcolor='grey',
                  arrowhead = 6,
                  arrowsize = 2,
                  ax = 0,
                  ay = 0,
                  axref="x",
                  ayref='y',
                  font = list(color = '#264E86',
                              family = 'sans serif',
                              size = 14))

p <- p %>%
  add_annotations(x = data["Toyota Corolla","wt"],
                  y = data["Toyota Corolla","mpg"],
                  text = "",
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  showarrow = TRUE,
                  arrowcolor='aquamarine',
                  arrowhead = 7,
                  arrowsize = 2,
                  ax = 0,
                  ay = 0,
                  axref="x",
                  ayref='y',
                  font = list(color = '#264E86',
                              family = 'sans serif',
                              size = 14))

p
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much! This is very helpful. Do you know if I can accomplish the same in 3D?

Comment: @ramonmb AFAIK that won't work. In order to get the arrow to point from origo to a set coordinate for `x,y` we had to set the argument `xref='x'` and `yref='y'`. So for a 3D chart we'd need to set a `zref0='z'` as well. And that does not exist ([check here](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-title-xref)) neither for `add_annotations` nor `layout()` which has an example that comes close your question [here](https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/#3d-annotations). So I't would seem that annotations are only set up to work in two dimensions.

Comment: What if we want a color gradient for the arrows? Is there a way to do that?